# ServiceConstructionException when creating a CXF web service client

Tags: web-services, cxf, webservice-client

I created a web service client and I am receiving the following error when the web service is being created. I was wondering if I am missing something on this error:

```
Error running SQL module: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not resolve a binding for null
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not resolve a binding for null
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:298)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:291)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:44)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.base.sql.SQLClientBase.setSecurityHeaderTokens(SQLClientBase.java:244)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.base.sql.SQLClientBase.get(SQLClientBase.java:292)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.module.sql.SQLModule.getBatch(SQLModule.java:149)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.module.sql.SQLModule.getAndProcessSQL(SQLModule.java:110)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.module.sql.SQLModule.run(SQLModule.java:280)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.GatewayClient.exec(GatewayClient.java:399)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.GatewayClient.run(GatewayClient.java:174)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.GatewayClient.main(GatewayClient.java:166)
Caused by: 
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not resolve a binding for null
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:404)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpointInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:258)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:146)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:51)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:115)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:437)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:296)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: 
org.apache.cxf.BusException: No binding factory for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/ registered.
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManagerImpl.getBindingFactory(BindingFactoryManagerImpl.java:91)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:394)
        ... 17 more
```

Here is the code:

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL WSDL_LOCATION=null;
if ( null == cl ) cl = SQLService.class.getClassLoader();
WSDL_LOCATION = cl.getResource( "SQLServiceSoap.wsdl" );
QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("https://myurl.org/services/myService?wsdl", "SQLService");
Service service = Service.create(WSDL_LOCATION,SERVICE_NAME);
SOAPport sqlService = service.getPort(SOAPport.class);
Client client = org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(sqlService);
Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, soapUser);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, PasswordCallbackHandler.class.getName());
outProps.put("password", soapPass);
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

String result = sqlService.ping("test");
```

This is where it dies: `SOAPport sqlService = service.getPort(SOAPport.class);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the soap binding on the classpath.   If using maven, do you have the cxf-rt-bindings-soap artifact as a dependency?

Comment: cxf.xml was missing, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`cxf.xml` was missing, that was the problem.