# How to solve ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for service?

Tags: web-services, cxf

I have a simple application with an web service created with `Apache CXF`. This application works when I run the server and the client (as `Java` applications). When I try to access the application `/services` URL which is mapped in `web.xml`, `Tomcat` gives me `404` error. When I run the project I receive:

> org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for service {http://sendmessage/}SendMessage

If anyone has any hints related to this error I would be glad to hear them. (I searched google and couldn't find something relevant to my situation)

Thank you!

Comment: Here is a related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006185/cxf-client-webservice-question

Answer (score 13):

I had same error, mine was related to namespace which were different in wsdl and webservice. So I changed them to the same.

WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions name=""
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/yourservice/"
```

Webservice class:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.example.org/yourservice/",
.........
```

Answer (score 3):

Even I had a similar issue. 
Fixed it by updating the jaxws:endpoint. 
I added the serviceName (mapping to the name present in the WSDL file) with the name space as defined in the "targetNamespace" defined in the wsdl:definitions tag.

```
<jaxws:endpoint id=".." implementor="..." serviceName="s:SERVICE_NAME_IN_WSDL"
xmlns:s="TARGET_NAME_SPACE_WSDL_DEFINTIONS"></jaxws:endpoint>
```

***edited(06Jul)*** 
Also, I have today that, with Apache CXF 3.0.5 version this issue is not coming;
But with Apache CXF 3.1 version, this is coming.

Answer (score 2):

ServiceConstructionException can occur at various stages when cxf compares the provided service, port and binding name with the wsdl it has already parsed. In this case ( and in most cases) it looks to be namespace issue.

`{http://sendmessage/}SendMessage` is either not present in parsed wsdl or the service name does not match with the [QName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html) present in the WSDL. There are other cases as well where binding or port does not match, one might receive the same exception. Following is a code snippit from `org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create()` method where it all happens.

If things are not clear why exactly it is happening your best bet is to debug this piece of code and see where it is failing and what is there in parsed wdsl definition (`com.ibm.wsdl.DefinitionImpl` in wsdl4j.jar).

```
        javax.wsdl.Service wsdlService = definition.getService(serviceName);
        if (wsdlService == null) {
            if ((!PartialWSDLProcessor.isServiceExisted(definition, serviceName))
                && (!PartialWSDLProcessor.isBindingExisted(definition, serviceName))
                && (PartialWSDLProcessor.isPortTypeExisted(definition, serviceName))) {
                try {
                    Map<QName, PortType> portTypes = CastUtils.cast(definition.getPortTypes());
                    String existPortName = null;
                    PortType portType = null;
                    for (QName existPortQName : portTypes.keySet()) {
                        existPortName = existPortQName.getLocalPart();
                        if (serviceName.getLocalPart().contains(existPortName)) {
                            portType = portTypes.get(existPortQName);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    WSDLFactory factory = WSDLFactory.newInstance();
                    ExtensionRegistry extReg = factory.newPopulatedExtensionRegistry();
                    Binding binding = PartialWSDLProcessor.doAppendBinding(definition, 
                                                                           existPortName, portType, extReg);
                    definition.addBinding(binding);
                    wsdlService = PartialWSDLProcessor.doAppendService(definition, 
                                                                       existPortName, extReg, binding);
                    definition.addService(wsdlService);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new ServiceConstructionException(new Message("NO_SUCH_SERVICE_EXC", LOG, serviceName));
                }
            } else {
                throw new ServiceConstructionException(new Message("NO_SUCH_SERVICE_EXC", LOG, serviceName));
            }
```

PS: I know this issue was opened back in 2011 but recently I faced the same issue and was able to resolve it. I hope it help others who are facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for port {http://localhost:9990/project/wsdl/targetName}targetNameSoap12.
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:179)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:428)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:548)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
... 13 more
```

Fixed problem, define at annotation @WebService(targetNameSpace = "targetNameSoap12") in your web service interface and in the contract WSDL.

For exemplo:

```
...
<wsdl:service name='targetName'>
  <wsdl:port binding='tns:targetNameSoap12' name='targetNameSoap12'>
...
```